# Как вывести результат работы в окно (графический интерфейс) - Java

Tags: java, gui

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Bank fr1 = new Bank();
    try {
        fr1.watch();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    jTextField1.getText(); [I]??????[/I]
}
```

Вообщем есть кнопка и текстовое окно, по нажатии этой кнопки выполняется метод **fr1.watch();**

Но, как сделать, чтобы результат работы этого метода выводился не на консоль, а в окно граф. интерфейса (TextField)?

Comment: `jTextField1.setText(...)`?

Comment: Не подходит,  методы нельзя засунуть в скобки.

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под `методы нельзя засунуть в скобки`?

Comment: Сама суть любого public void подразумевает что метод ничего не возвращает. Чтобы вывести результат работы метода в текстовое поле его нужно переделать в 
public watch(int a){
return a;
}
где а - это результат работы вашего метода.
потом с помощью метода setText(fr1.watch()); устанавливаете текст

Answer (score 0):

```
void watch() throws IOException {
    JFrame sc1= new JFrame();
    String line;
    int n;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "windows-1251");            
    String name = "Комаров Сергей Влдаимирович";
    try(BufferedReader bw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(""+name+".txt")))
    {                        
        sc1.jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf("Установка соединения..." + "\n"));     
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {                  
        sc1.jTextField1.setText(ex.getMessage());
    }          
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А что у вас значат звёздочки вокруг функции?